# how to run jmeter with ANT

Tags: ant, jmeter

I want to display Jmeter results via html. the html dashboard is not informative enough, so I want to use the ant solution.

- I installed ant as expected
- I took my testplan.jmx and copy it to 
  C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras
- I changet the testplan.jmx to Test.jtl
- I entered to cmd cd C:\Jmeter_4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras
- I entered ant and press enter

the test plan always take 20 minutes and in ant 12 second that is very stange since I have delay of 15 minutes.
I opened Test.html and instead of seeing results I saw the test plan as xml. and jmeter not start or even worked. what I am missing , why ant not runnung the testplan. the results is not even html see pic[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your file to `Test.jmx`, not to `Test.jtl`.

If there is a `Test.jtl` file already there - you will need to delete it as by default [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter) will add new results into existing `Test.jtl` file which is not something you should be looking for.

---

There is another option: you can generate Ant-style HTML report from .jtl results file.

1. Execute your script "normally" in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l Test.jtl
   ```
2. Copy `Test.jtl` file to "extras" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Execute `ant xslt-report` command.
4. That's it, you should see the results in HTML form as `Test.html` file

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on different ways of running a JMeter test from command line and from Java code.